# extjs do some action with window components on it's load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to disable a button on window when this window pops up but whatever handlers I tried to apply, window in not poped up and just spits out that "undefined" staff to me. For example I tried:

```
window.onload = Ext.getCmp('buttonId').disable();
```

and it returns me this in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'disable' of undefined
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not have an`id` set on the button...

Why don't you disable the button directly?

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Disabled button',
    disabled:true
});
```

If you have an `id` on there, it works:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Dynamically disabled Button',
    id:'dynamicBtn',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.getCmp('dynamicBtn').disable();
    },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fPSf/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems that button is not initialized yet when I'm trying to disable it. I do this in init() function controller, so button seems to be not initialized yet. Where should I call it?

Comment: This answer is wrong. `onload` expects a reference to a function. You're assigning the result of disable (the component). Also, you shouldn't be rendering a button outside of an `Ext.onReady`.

Comment: So then add the correct answer or edit this answer to be correct! Don't just complain about it.

Comment: Using `launch` solved the problem! Thanks! Please, add this to your answer.